# How to change datestyle in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a PostgreSQL database in gcp and I would like to change the datestyle to dd/mm/yyyy. From other answers I know that you could usually do this by changing the postgresql.config. However, I don't know how to this in google cloud.

Comment: You can change it in your session with `SET`. Also, I am sure that your hosting provider will offer some way to change parameters.

Comment: @Belayer your comment would work better as answer

Comment: @JAHDZP OK. I'll do that way. I sometimes wonder which to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off discard the notion that a date (or timestamp) has a particular format (datestyle). Internally it is a integer; the format is for conversion and display only. The trouble with editing the config file and setting the session level is you depend upon implicate conversion conversion. A better approach is to specify the the format desired thus using explicit conversion. (Yes, more typing, but more control). See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=16fcae795929eb937d685809fd0223fc).